# Error trying to register a payment

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In invoice when i'm trying to register a payment this error message shows up :

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:

- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set
  [object with reference: name - name]

I cheked the access rights but nothing, the error message still appears.

- Note1: I am able to register payment if I use admin user.
- Note2: Not sure if it could be releated with having multicompany enabled.

EDIT1:
Checking Odoo server logs I found this:

bad query: INSERT INTO "account_full_reconcile" ("id", "name", "create_uid", "write_uid", "create_date", "write_date") VALUES(nextval('account_full_reconcile_id_seq'), NULL, 7, 7, (now() at time zone 'UTC'), (now() at time zone 'UTC')) RETURNING id

EDIT2:
In the previous bad query error can be seen that problem is that "name" field is Null.Label for this field is "Number".

So checking "account_full_reconcile" table in Odoo database, in the column "name" I have two non-consecutive values: "A1" and "A4".
Also in column "id" there are non-consecutive id: "19" and "30". Not sure if It's related with the error.

Comment: This question was originally asked by other user in https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/error-register-a-payment-101394.

Comment: With multi company enabled, it could be that all accounting features like periods, journals, etc. are not configured correctly. Did you check that? Is there a journal for your active company?

Comment: Yes, I checked it and seems ok to me: 
Under Accounting > Configuration > Accounting there are Journals, Taxes, Fiscal Positions and Bank Accounts for my active company. Note "Spain - Accounting (PGCE 2008)" app is installed.

Comment: What about payment terms? Do you use them? It seems that payment terms are multi-company ready, too, but you can't see the company on them. Try to find out, if there is a problem. (had the same issue on a customer of us)

Comment: I don't use payment terms, but using it nothing change and I still get same error. Maybe error is related with what I tell in the question edit 2.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace from the log?

Comment: I have just post the log in EDIT3, let me now if there is too much information in order remove unnecessary lines.

Comment: It's not helpful :-( Does the used Journal has set a sequence? You can only see this field in debug mode of Odoo.

Comment: My Journals (Bank and Cash) have both "Entry Sequence" (Bank and Cash too). For example for Bank Entry Sequence has implementation=no gap; preffix=BNK1/%(range_year)s/ and there is a subsequence with field number_next and number_next_actual both equal to 6.

Comment: account_full_reconcile was introduced in feb 2016. Didn't know that until now ;-) The field name should get the next number from ir.sequence with code "account.reconcile". Can you please check if this sequence is set correctly?

Comment: In ir_sequence table I only have a row with code = account.reconcile (id=2 and padding=0).  Last row has id=22 and no code value. In account_full_reconcile table last row has id=76 and name=A9.  There are more register than I said in EDIT2 because Odoo let me register payments with admin user. I don't understand from what field of ir_sequence table name field is supposed to get the next number, id, padding,...?

Comment: i'm out of ideas, sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found out...I had to manually create an "account Reconcile Sequence" record for the 2nd company...just duplicated and cahnge Company.  From Technical  -- sequences  -- Account reconcile sequence.

Comment: Good One!. 

As I understand the "account Reconcile Sequence" duplication should be automatically trigger when a new company is added to the multicompany option, so probably this is a bug.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem but I don't know where to create this other sequence record. Can you elaborate a bit more ? Thanks.

Comment: Go to  "Settings" (in topbar) > "Technical" (sidebar section) > "Sequences & Identifiers" > "Sequences" and search for "account.reconcile".

If you don't see "Technical" section , activate the developer mode in user menu (top-right corner) > "About" and click in "Activate the developer mode"

Answer (score 4):

In odoo 9 the screen at "From Technical -- sequences -- Account reconcile sequence" doesn't have option to set company, so odoo9 users can do just duplicate it and create a new record and from backend in the database update that new record company_id value with your compant id